# NWJS (node-webkit) window functions not working

Tags: javascript, window, node-webkit, nw.js

EDIT 2:
I found out in web2exe application: Include NODEjs needs to be checked. That solved my problem.

I am using web2exe application for automated exe packaging, so I need only two functions from NWJS:

Exit an application (close window) and toggle between window and fullscreen.

I found some code for this, but when I placed it in my main JS file, nothing happens. What I am doing wrong?
Edit: I found a following code:

```js
function winclose() {
 var gui = require('nw.gui');
  var win = gui.Window.get();
  win.close();
 }
```

When I call this function, nothing happens. I do not have Inspect Element, so I cant see any errors.
And I can assure you, my code is perfectly clear, without any bugs, and this function and call to it is placed correctly.

So, could it be, that I need to write this code in to another source file and not in my own? Or maybe this application (web2exe), is interfering somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `win.close(true)` ? To clarify it you really need to enable devtools.